# How to adapt size of items without changing ratio in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, row

I am considerably new to Compose so my question might be pretty trivial, but, here's what's up.

I am trying to create a grid app of 14 elements. 14 cards with a fixed ratio inside it.

[image]

This is the longest text we have so you can tell that the size doesn't get thrown off and the text doesn't over flow

[image]

I'd like to maintain the same ratio as I put it in a horizontal grid with all the other elements, but when I do, the sizes instantly get messed up instead of adapting in size to fit the screen.

[image]

This is what I get ^^^^ and this is what I want to get ˘˘˘˘˘

[image]

Here is my code for the grid and the cards:

```
    val number = topic.numbers.toString()
    Card{

Row {


            Image(painter = painterResource(topic.image), contentDescription = stringResource(topic.name),
                modifier
                    .size(68.dp)
                    .fillMaxHeight())
       Column(modifier.width(120.dp)){Text(LocalContext.current.getString(topic.name),
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
               .padding(top = 16.dp)
               .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
            ,style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium)

Row(modifier = Modifier,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
){
    Icon(painterResource(R.drawable.ic_grain), contentDescription = "few dots",
        Modifier
            .padding(start = 16.dp)
            .padding(end = 8.dp))
    Text((number), modifier)

}
       }

}
    }
}


@Composable

fun GridList(gridList: List<Topic>, modifier: Modifier){
    LazyHorizontalGrid(rows = GridCells.Fixed(7), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)) {
        items(topics) { topic ->
            Topics(topic = topic, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#lazy-grids) of [`LazyVerticalGrid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) and [`LazyHorizontalGrid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyHorizontalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)):

> A Lazy vertical grid will display its items in a vertically scrollable container, spanned across multiple columns, while the Lazy horizontal grids will have the same behaviour on the horizontal axis.

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. But in your current solution, you will have

- a Grid
- with 7 rows
- that scrolls horizontally.

As the `LazyHorizontalGrid` is **by definition horizontally scrollable, you can't force the items to fit the width of the screen**. If they are too wide to fit the screen, the screen will just enable horizontal scrolling.

So it seems like you rather want a `LazyVerticalGrid`. You can implement it as follows:

```
LazyVericalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
) {
    items(topics) { topic ->
        Topics(topic = topic, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    }
}
```